# How to build a Flink application with Maven in Linux

Tags: linux, maven, apache-flink, development-environment

I'm using Maven to manage my custom Flink application in a CentOS server. And I'm a beginner of Java.

To build an empty project, I just followed the [official doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/projectsetup/java_api_quickstart.html), which means that I executed the command below:

```
mvn archetype:generate                               \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.flink              \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=flink-quickstart-java      \
      -DarchetypeVersion=1.10.0
```

It works. I get a project as below:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── myflink
        │       ├── BatchJob.java
        │       └── StreamingJob.java
        └── resources
            └── log4j.properties
```

After that, I modify the file `StreamingJob.java` with the simple example `WordCount`.

Then I execute `mvn clean package` to try to build my jar file.

As my understanding, I should get two jar files, one is for the `BatchJob.java`, the other is for the `StreamingJob.java` (which is the example of `WordCount`).

However, after executing the command `mvn clean package`, I get `myflink-1.jar` and `original-myflink-1.jar`. I can't figure out what they are. Furthermore, it doesn't seem that the `BatchJob.java` and the `StreamingJob.java` have their own jar files.

So what is the file `myflink-1.jar`? Does it contain the two java files? If I want to get a jar file, which contains only the `StreamingJob.java`, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jar file is for your entire package which typically aggregate java class files, some metadata, resource files. The reason it is `jar` is because of `<packaging>jar</packaging>` defined in pom.xml. If you expand your `jar` file you would see both the `java` class files in respective package.

The reason we see 2 `jar` file is due to the addition of Maven Shade Plugin. The first `jar`(`flint-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`) is generated from the default `maven jar` plugin and the other one(`original-flint-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`) from the maven shade plugin.

Maven Shade plugin helps us generate uber-jar/ fat jar. We can also control the dependency i.e include/exclude dependency as done in this sample flink project. So when you run `mvn clean package` you should see some dependency are being excluded as defined in `pom.xml` file as shown below

```
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:3.1.1:shade (default) @ flint-demo ---
[INFO] Excluding org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.15 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
```

To know more about the maven shade plugin you can check [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) and [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/maven/maven-shade-plugin-example/)

If you want to exclude any file i.e in your case say BatchJob you can use Maven Compiler Plugin. I see in sample project maven compiler plugin is already present so you need to just include the `<excludes>`, something like below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/flint/demo/BatchJob.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now when you do `mvn clean package` and check the `jar` file you should not see `BatchJob` class file.

```
$ jar tf flint-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
com/
com/flint/
com/flint/demo/
com/flint/demo/StreamingJob.class
log4j.properties
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.flint.demo/
META-INF/maven/com.flint.demo/flint-demo/
META-INF/maven/com.flint.demo/flint-demo/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.flint.demo/flint-demo/pom.properties
```

To know more about Maven Compiler plugin check [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/)